# Devise is using default templates for mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

I'm using Devise with custom views. Everything is working all right except mailer, which is still sending the emails with default email templates.

I have set the default locale to 'fr', do I have to rename also mailer views from *password_change.html.erb* to *password_change.fr.html.erb*?

I tried that and it didn't help though.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So solved, for anyone in the future:

The important when using custom controllers is to set

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

in */config/initializers/devise.rb* file.